# Removing tags (<td>, <tr> and <p> from a dataframe and then exporting to csv and emailing

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tags, export-to-excel

I am a learning, and frustrated novice in python! I am trying to extract soccer scores from our school website and email them to a list of parents so they can stay updated on the progress of the team.  I created a data frame and tried to export but all the tags come through and data is jumbled up. I didn't even get to the emailing out part but will try and learn that in the next step.  Thanks for any and all help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd


url = "https://southkentschool.org/athletics/teams/varsity-soccer/schedule-scores"
html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

data_source = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "ss-content-block"})
data_table = data_source.tbody.find_all("tr")  
print(type(data_table))
print(data_table)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_table)
print(df)
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'export_dataframe.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of `print(data_table)` ? shall we assume that if you want to remove <td>, <tr> and <p> you also want to remove </td>, </tr> and </p> too ?

Comment: yes I want to try and get the data into a readable form into a csv file.